# How do I access Acumatica Odata for general inquiry?

Tags: odata, acumatica

I set up a general inquiry in Acumatica. How do I access this endpoint using ODATA via Postman rather than a REST API custom endpoint?

Comment: does the Acumatica help provide any support here: https://help-2022r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=46d3beed-0faf-4908-b5f4-1c282a110c4d

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the 'Allow OData access' checkbox is set to true in the GI.

After that you can access it via the following URL https://{site URL}/OData/{GI NAME}

For additional details look at the following articles:
https://help-2022r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=5d97a93d-45e0-466e-ba5e-77e1ccf96643

https://help-2022r1.acumatica.com/Help?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=265a8850-3071-47c4-a4fe-a589d5895ce9